# Can I have a small wage if I establish a non-profit organization/company in Greece?

Tags: small-business, non-profit, greece

In the future I plan to make a non-profit organization, so I can hire software engineers in order to contribute and develop [libre software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects. The organization will either be in Greece or Cyprus.

Can I have myself a small wage (in some circumstances e.g. when the organization has too many donations, more than it needs to be sustainable)?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do so?  Many non-profits have paid employees.

Comment: yes but Idk whether is legal to be an employee of my own "non-profit" org that I have founded.

Answer (score 1):

A non-profit is created and run by a board of directors.  Although you would be on the board initially, you would have no absolute right to be on the board, and the board could choose to replace you with someone else. There is nothing special about being a founder of a non-profit.

A board member of a non-profit may be paid for their time, though often they are not.

Many non-profits have employees who are paid a salary, and you can be on the board and also be an employee.

This is all from a U.S.A. perspective but I expect it is the same for Greece.